# Search string for dictionary key and if contains, display that keys value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, twitter

I am trying to have my program read a tweet, and look for a company name in that tweet by looking in my dictionary. If it finds a company name, I want it to return the ticker connected to that company name. I can get it to work when the dictionary key is a single word but it won't show it its a multi-word key like CHINA UNICOM or EXPRESS SCRIPTS. Any suggestions? I know that splitting the tweet makes it difficult to search for multi-word strings but its the only way I could make it work for single word company names like FACEBOOK and GOOGLE. Thanks, here's my code. (the input is just the tweet i'm just manually entering them for now until I figure out how to get this to work)

```
dictionary = 
{'apple':'AAPL',
'google':'GOOG',
'alphabet':'GOOGL',
'microsoft':'MSFT',
'amazon':'AMZN',
'facebook':'FB',
'express scripts':'ESRX',
'china unicom':'CHU'}

data = "Google is in talks to acquire China Unicom"
tweet = data.lower()

if any(word in tweet for word in dictionary.keys()):
    for x in tweet.split():
        if x in dictionary.keys():
            print(dictionary[x])
```

The output I am looking for would be GOOG and CHU but I only get GOOG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a conditional comprehension:

```
dictionary = {'apple':'AAPL',
'google':'GOOG',
'alphabet':'GOOGL',
'microsoft':'MSFT',
'amazon':'AMZN',
'facebook':'FB',
'express scripts':'ESRX',
'china unicom':'CHU'}

data = 'Google is in talks to acquire China Unicom'

tweet = data.lower()

found = (dictionary[key] for key in dictionary.keys() if key in tweet)

for item in found:
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
GOOG
CHU
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to print only the ticker connected to that company name, You can use:

```
dictionary = 
{'apple':'AAPL',
'google':'GOOG',
'alphabet':'GOOGL',
'microsoft':'MSFT',
'amazon':'AMZN',
'facebook':'FB'}

data = input()
tweet = data.lower()

for key in dictionary.keys():
    if key in tweet:
        print(dictionary[key])
```

And no matter how many are words will be in input, it will run for all key in dictionary and check matching with tweet and if true print ticker

Comment: Thanks for your help but this doesn't solve my problem. This issue i'm having is that it wont recognize any company name that is two words long, like Express Scripts - it only works for company names that are one word long like Facebook or Google.